# Custom error handler not working in Express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm trying to use a custom error handler for my Express routes but can't get it to work. I've followed the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) where they say you have to put you're handler at the very end of the `use` chain but it still looks like the default error handler gets called.

I've simplified my project to the very basic and this is what I have. I'm only calling the `start` method on an `App` instance to get the server to start listening.

```
import * as express from "express";
import { Express, Request, Response } from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";

export class App {

    private static readonly port: number = 8080;
    
    private app: Express;

    public constructor() {
        this.app = express();
        this.app
            .use(bodyParser.json())
            .get("/", (): void => {
                throw new Error("Error from UserRoute class");
            })
            .use((_: Request, res: Response): void => {
                console.log("Requested route not found");
                res.status(404)
                    .send({ error: "Not found" });
            })
            .use((err: any, _: Request, res: Response): void => {
                console.error("Unexpected error: ", err.stack);
                res.status(500)
                    .send({ error: "An unexpected error occured" });
            });
    }

    public start(): void {
        this.app.listen(App.port, (): void => {
            console.log("Server started!");
        });
    }

}
```

The 404 works, but when I make a request using Postman at http://localhost:8080/ I get the following as the response body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Error: Error from UserRoute class<br>
&nbsp; &nbsp;at E:\Programming\leslie\server\build\app.js:12:19<br>
&nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Programming\leslie\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)<br>
&nbsp; &nbsp;at next (E:\Programming\leslie\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)<br>
&nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (E:\Programming\leslie\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)<br>
&nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Programming\leslie\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)<br>
&nbsp; &nbsp;at E:\Programming\leslie\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22<br>
&nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (E:\Programming\leslie\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)<br>
&nbsp; &nbsp;at next (E:\Programming\leslie\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)<br>
&nbsp; &nbsp;at E:\Programming\leslie\server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5<br>
&nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (E:\Programming\leslie\server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your error-handling middleware is not defined as an actual error-handler, as the `next`-argument is missing. Changing it to the following should fix the issue:

```
.use((err: any, _: Request, res: Response, next: Function): void => {
       console.error("Unexpected error: ", err.stack);
       res.status(500).send({ error: "An unexpected error occured" });
});
```

Comment: This worked! Wasn't expecting Express to check how many parameters the callback function had. Thank you!